# Camel test fails when starting blueprint bundle

Tags: apache-camel

My camel test fails to start when I try to create the Camel context from my blueprint xml config file. Seems to be missing a snappyjava.dll.

Does anyone have experience with this type of issue?

I am running my test using gradle 2.6 and Java 1.8.0_60 on a windows 8.1 platform.

My blueprint xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

    <!-- Defined the real JAXRS back end service  -->
    <cxf:rsServer id="lookUpService"
                  address="http://localhost:8083/someapp/rest"
                  serviceClass="com.somecompany.someapp.MyEndpoint">
        <cxf:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="customerService"/>
        </cxf:serviceBeans>
    </cxf:rsServer>

    <bean id="routBuilder" class="com.somecompany.someapp.SomeRoute"/>

    <camelContext id="someapp" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <routeBuilder ref="routBuilder"/>
    </camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

My dependencies in the gradle project are:

```
compile 'dk.sosi.seal:seal:2.2.6'
compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-servlet:2.15.1'
compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-test-blueprint:2.15.1'
compile 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:3.0.4'
compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1'
compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-blueprint:2.15.1'
compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-jms:2.15.1'
compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-cxf:2.15.1'
compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-stream:2.15.1'
compile 'org.apache.activemq:apache-activemq:5.11.0'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.apache.camel:camel-test:2.15.1'
```

and I get the following output on standard err when running the test:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/svt/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.activemq/activemq-all/5.11.0/5bcc10ea13c5723c1587f54245616cae1243b54c/activemq-all-5.11.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/svt/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.10/b3eeae7d1765f988a1f45ea81517191315c69c9e/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
15/09/25 15:25:58 INFO blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper: Using Blueprint XML file: /C:/someapp/build/resources/main/OSGI-INF.blueprint/someapp.xml
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO metadata.RawBuilder: Copy thread finished.
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO osgi.Activator: Camel activator starting
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO osgi.Activator: Camel activator started
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to start bundle
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSRBundle.start(PojoSRBundle.java:144)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSR.startBundles(PojoSR.java:406)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSR.<init>(PojoSR.java:323)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoServiceRegistryFactoryImpl.newPojoServiceRegistry(PojoServiceRegistryFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:137)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:102)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.setUp(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
... <cut stuff out to fit in stackoverflow post> ...    
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no snappyjava.dll in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyBundleActivator.start(SnappyBundleActivator.java:58)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSRBundle.start(PojoSRBundle.java:132)
    ... 54 more
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/clustering
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/bindings/soap
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to start bundle
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSRBundle.start(PojoSRBundle.java:144)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSR.startBundles(PojoSR.java:406)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSR.<init>(PojoSR.java:323)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoServiceRegistryFactoryImpl.newPojoServiceRegistry(PojoServiceRegistryFactoryImpl.java:51)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:137)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:102)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.createBundleContext(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintTestSupport.setUp(CamelBlueprintTestSupport.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
... <cut stuff out to fit in stackoverflow post> ...    
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/Plugin
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework.PojoSRBundle.start(PojoSRBundle.java:130)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 67 more
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO container.BlueprintExtender: No quiesce support is available, so blueprint components will not participate in quiesce operations
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty (8) [org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyDestinationFactory, org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.ContinuationProviderFactory]
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.camel.camel-cxf-transport (15) [org.apache.camel.component.cxf.transport.CamelTransportFactory]
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws (17) [org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextResourceResolver]
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-soap (20) [org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory, org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory]
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http (68) [org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPWSDLExtensionLoader, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPClientAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.HTTPServerAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.transport.http.policy.NoOpPolicyInterceptorProvider]
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-xml (73) [org.apache.cxf.binding.xml.XMLBindingFactory, org.apache.cxf.binding.xml.wsdl11.XMLWSDLExtensionLoader]
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-ws-addr (75) [org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.AddressingAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.UsingAddressingAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.policy.AddressingPolicyInterceptorProvider, org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.impl.AddressingWSDLExtensionLoader, org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.WSAddressingFeature$WSAddressingFeatureApplier, org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.MAPAggregator$MAPAggregatorLoader]
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-wsdl (77) [org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager]
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Adding the extensions from bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-ws-policy (108) [org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyEngine, org.apache.cxf.policy.PolicyDataEngine, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistry, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyInterceptorProviderRegistry, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyAnnotationListener, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.ServiceModelPolicyProvider, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.external.DomainExpressionBuilderRegistry, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.external.EndpointReferenceDomainExpressionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.external.URIDomainExpressionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.attachment.wsdl11.Wsdl11AttachmentPolicyProvider, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.mtom.MTOMAssertionBuilder, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.mtom.MTOMPolicyInterceptorProvider]
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core
15/09/25 15:25:59 INFO blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/beans
... <cut stuff out to fit in stackoverflow post> ...    
15/09/25 15:26:00 INFO blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd
15/09/25 15:26:00 INFO blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#
15/09/25 15:26:00 INFO blueprint.NamespaceHandlerRegisterer: Registered blueprint namespace handler for http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702
15/09/25 15:26:00 INFO rest.MyTestCase: ********************************************************************************
15/09/25 15:26:00 INFO rest.MyTestCase: Testing: testFile2QueueRouteBuilderWithMockEndpointExtension(com.somecompany.someapp.rest.MyTestCase)
15/09/25 15:26:00 INFO rest.MyTestCase: ********************************************************************************
15/09/25 15:26:00 INFO container.BlueprintContainerImpl: Bundle MyTestCase is waiting for namespace handlers [http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf]
15/09/25 15:26:30 WARN blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper: Test bundle headers: Bundle-ManifestVersion=2, Bundle-Name=System Bundle, Bundle-SymbolicName=de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework, Bundle-Vendor=kalpatec, Bundle-Version=0.2.1
15/09/25 15:26:30 WARN blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper: ServiceReference: [org.codehaus.stax2.osgi.Stax2ValidationSchemaFactoryProvider], bundle: woodstox-core-asl [106], symbolicName: woodstox-core-asl
15/09/25 15:26:30 WARN blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper: ServiceReference: [org.codehaus.stax2.osgi.Stax2InputFactoryProvider], bundle: woodstox-core-asl [106], symbolicName: woodstox-core-asl
... <cut stuff out to fit in stackoverflow post> ...    
15/09/25 15:26:30 WARN blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper: ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-http [59], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-http
15/09/25 15:26:30 WARN blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper: ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler], bundle: org.apache.cxf.cxf-core [67], symbolicName: org.apache.cxf.cxf-core
15/09/25 15:26:30 WARN blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper: ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-servlet [6], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-servlet
15/09/25 15:26:30 WARN blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper: ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver], bundle: org.apache.activemq.activemq-camel [21], symbolicName: org.apache.activemq.activemq-camel
15/09/25 15:26:30 WARN blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper: ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService], bundle: org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http [68], symbolicName: org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http
15/09/25 15:26:30 WARN blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper: ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainer], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-cxf-transport [15], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-cxf-transport
15/09/25 15:26:30 WARN blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper: ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler], bundle: org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-rs-client [76], symbolicName: org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-rs-client
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO rest.MyTestCase: ********************************************************************************
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO rest.MyTestCase: Testing done: testFile2QueueRouteBuilderWithMockEndpointExtension(com.somecompany.someapp.rest.MyTestCase)
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO rest.MyTestCase: Took: 31.460 seconds (31460 millis)
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO rest.MyTestCase: ********************************************************************************
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO container.BlueprintExtender: Destroying BlueprintContainer for bundle MyTestCase
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Removing the extensions for bundle 68
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Removing the extensions for bundle 8
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Removing the extensions for bundle 73
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Removing the extensions for bundle 75
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Removing the extensions for bundle 108
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Removing the extensions for bundle 77
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Removing the extensions for bundle 15
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Removing the extensions for bundle 17
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO osgi.CXFActivator: Removing the extensions for bundle 20
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO container.BlueprintExtender: Destroying BlueprintContainer for bundle org.apache.aries.blueprint
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO container.BlueprintExtender: Destroying BlueprintContainer for bundle org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-features-clustering
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO container.BlueprintExtender: Destroying BlueprintContainer for bundle org.apache.camel.camel-cxf-transport
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO container.BlueprintExtender: Destroying BlueprintContainer for bundle org.apache.camel.camel-cxf
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO container.BlueprintExtender: Destroying BlueprintContainer for bundle org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO osgi.Activator: Camel activator stopping
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO osgi.Activator: Camel activator stopped
15/09/25 15:26:30 INFO blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper: Deleting work directory target/bundles/1443187558935
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue was not the inability of IntelliJ to running tests on a camel context defined by an OSGI blueprint, but rather a series of issues in the blueprint XML and in my dependencies.

I updated my blueprint XML to:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
           xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">

    <!-- Defined the real JAXRS back end service  -->
    <cxf:rsServer id="lookUpService"
           address="http://localhost:8083/"
           serviceClass="com.somecompany.someapp.MyEndpoint">
    </cxf:rsServer>

    <bean id="routBuilder" class="com.somecompany.someapp.SomeRoute"/>

    <camel:camelContext id="someapp">
        <camel:routeBuilder ref="routBuilder"/>
    </camel:camelContext>

</blueprint>
```

and modfied some of my dependencies:

```
compile 'dk.sosi.seal:seal:2.2.6'
compile 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:3.1.3'
compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1'
compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-blueprint:2.15.1'
compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-jms:2.15.1'
compile ('org.apache.camel:camel-cxf:2.15.1') {
    exclude group: 'asm', module: 'asm'
}
compile 'org.apache.camel:camel-http:2.15.1'
compile 'org.ow2.asm:asm-all:4.0'
compile ('org.apache.activemq:apache-activemq:5.11.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.activemq', module: 'activemq-leveldb-store'
}
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.10'
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.apache.camel:camel-test-blueprint:2.15.1'
testCompile 'org.apache.camel:camel-test:2.15.1'
```

Especially excluding the wrong version (3.3.1) of ASM from CXF and including version 4.0 helped. (Thanks to Dennis Bohnstedt Hansen).

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are missing snappy-java in your classpath and you need it add as a dependency in your pom.xml? See here for similar issue.
http://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-snappyjava-in-java-library-path-error/

Comment: I tried it, but it seems it's already included as a dependency of activemq.

Tried to comment out my activemq dependency, which made the problem go away (replaced by another). Would like to include activemq at some point though.

Comment: Can you run this as a local camel context without the osgi deployment?

Comment: I am running it from my IntelliJ IDEA. So that is without osgi deployment, right?

Comment: have you tried adding the dll to your path as mentioned here? https://broadinstitute.github.io/picard/using-snappy-in-picard.html#Obtaining

Comment: by the way, which OSGI container are you deploying it to?

Comment: I am planning to deploy it to JBoss Fuse 6.2. But I am still just running it as a JUnit test, so there should not be any osgi involved, yet.

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with the path to the snappyjava.dll. It does not seem to find it in the classpath. But you should be able to run this without a JUnit test to see that things work. In JBoss Developer Studio you can run blueprint.xml files as local camel context without osgi deployment. Not sure you can do that in IntelliJ.